# Python: print list of numbers in scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing, scientific-notation

**Background:**

```
local_print = [0.03, 535, 7]
```

This can be printed in scientific notation using following

```
for x in local_print:
    print('{:.3e}'.format(x))
```

Without scientific notation this can be printed as follows:

```
print(*local_print, sep='\t')
```

**Question**

Is there any way to combine these two printing methods? I want to print using

```
print(*local_print, sep='\t')
```

in scientific format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a list comprehension

```
local_print = [0.03, 535, 7]
print('\t'.join(['{:.3e}'.format(x) for x in local_print]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to use a generator expression:

```
 print(*('{:.3e}'.format(x) for x in local_print), sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more lay man way, just print from a different list.

```
scientific = []
for x in local_print:
    scientific.append('{:.3e}'.format(x))
print(*scientific, sep='\t')
```

Output:

```
3.000e-02      5.350e+02      7.000e+00
```